Getting rid of nested loops while cropping a multidimensional tensor
I'm currently developing a function that takes in input a tensor like: torch.Size([21, 19, 83, 83]),
where dim = 0 is time, dim = 1 is patterns, and the remaining 2 are the size of an individual pattern.
Now, my objective is to crop as much as possible the individual tensors of size 83x83 by getting rid of the unnecessary zeros, and then pad so that a pattern is in the top left corner.
Each tensor is filled with [-1,0,1] and usually the states 1 and -1 are near each other, while being sorrounded by many zeros.
ex (on a smaller scale):
[0,0,0,0]
[0,1,0,0]
[0,0,-1,0]
[0,0,0,0]  

the cropped and pad grid would be:
[1,0,0,0]
[0,-1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]  

my current solution is:
def crop_tensor(input):
    # Initialize a tensor to hold the results
    result = torch.zeros_like(input)

    # Loop over the time and pattern type dimensions
    for t in range(input.shape[0]):
        for p in range(input.shape[1]):
            # Get the current matrix
            matrix = input[t, p]

            # Find the non-zero elements
            non_zero_indices = torch.nonzero(matrix)

            # Crop the matrix
            min_indices = torch.min(non_zero_indices, dim=0)[0]
            max_indices = torch.max(non_zero_indices, dim=0)[0]
            cropped_matrix = 
            matrix[min_indices[0]:max_indices[0]+1, min_indices[1]:max_indices[1]+1]

            # Pad the matrix back to its original size and place it in the result tensor
            result[t, p, :cropped_matrix.shape[0], :cropped_matrix.shape[1]] = cropped_matrix

    return result

but unfortunately it is far too slow.
I tried vectorizing but I wasn't able to, additionaly AI assistants are not capable of helping either.
